# Programming to an Interface and Keep Testability in Unique Classes

Tags: programming-practices, interfaces, solid

I try to program to an interface whenever possible, but when I have a class that fulfills a very specific and unique purpose, one that can't be abstracted. Is it correct for me to say that I've reached the limits of "abstraction" and that I need to just pass in the concrete class?

```
public void DoSomethingWith (HighlySpecificClass specificClass, ISomeInterface abstractedClass)
```

So if the "program to an interface" is more a guideline than a hard rule, how can I make it testable? Should I create a "header" interface for it anyway?

Comment: I think you can try to implement some base class or interface for your HighlySpecificClass. But if your HighlySpecificClass does not share any function or property with other classes / interfaces by design, I think it should be ok to just use it for the interface definition.

Comment: @gnat not exactly, I'm trying to determine the specific case where the design of "what the code is doing" is necessarily highly specific. Would I still make it a "header" interface?

Answer (score 0):

'Program to an interface' is a general, language-independent statement. With languages like C# and Java that have an explicit language feature called `interface`, this can lead to [confusion](http://mortoray.com/2014/08/01/the-false-abstraction-antipattern/).

The thing to remember is that both languages have at least two ways of defining interfaces;

- explicitly, with a keyword
- implcitly, by taking a class and making only the relevant bits accessible (with `public` etc.).

Knowing when to use which way of defining an interface is in general a judgement call.

Sometimes a specific technology or tool will make the decision for you. For example, if you were using a mocking tool that only supports mocking interfaces, and a particular test needs a thing to be mocked, then you are going to have to use an explicit interface.

But ideally you would use a less limited tool that supported both explicit and implicit interfaces.